# Can I solve this one without strictNullChecks: false?

Tags: typescript, strictnullchecks

I wonder how can I solve this without setting `strictNullchecks` to false.

```
if (someArray.find(element => element.id === x.id) {
    return someArray.find(element => element.id === x.id).message
}
```

or

```
const x = someArray.find(element => element.id === x.id) ? someArray.find(element => element.id === x.id).message : "No message"
```

As you know, TypeScript shows an error like "Object is possibly undefined" when I set the `strictNullChecks` to true.

Is it the best choice to set the `strictNullChecks` to false?

------- added contents -------

[screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLKkt.png)

```
if (self.cases.find(element => element.code === self.statusCode)) {

                // NOTE: do not use 'case' to variable instead of the 'selectedCase'
                const selectedCase = self.cases.find(element => element.code === self.statusCode)
                console.log(selectedCase.message)
                return (
                    self.statusCode + " " + selectedCase.message
                )
            }
```

Q1. When I try to use 'case' as variable. It requires variable declaration. is it pre-declared words?

Q2. the `console.log(selectedCase.message)` and `selectedCase.message` occur the error `Object is possibly undefined` also.

Why this happens..?

Comment: Just extract `someArray.find(element => element.id === x.id)` to a variable, that way you don't have to run the loop twice anyway.

Comment: But both your examples seem to work in the playground anyway: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUBnOBbApgQQCdCBDATwC5ESwyBtAXQBpEAPKmsgSioykJhgA5ogDeAKERTEMYIkw4CxcgDpgggCZpcAG1x4wURAF4AfIl37chlTA0njxtrY1cuYydK+FcUEISQsPCJSMjVNbT0DIzMLKOsoFwcnVhcuFTwMDBIhXABuTykAX0LEHz8AxAAiADk4REzs3KqCkvFQSFgERAAjEkIFYOVKalpGFnZR7l5+QREJb19-QMUQ1XUwLUtok3NthKTHFLTSrwB+RCClUPDNyKtDXbiHxLtk5zt0xpzcU+kqWr1b7NVridrgaDwJB9ABeg2u5A4Y2YbCR00us2EHi8EAQfDiJkuq2Gty28UesX2NjeRw+rgKiwqSF0iAuugyuCyP0QALqDU5TVwLXEJSAA

Comment: `someArray.find(element => element.id === x.id)?.message`?

Comment: VLAZ, your comment is working. Thank you! (But I got some additional questions... )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than searching the array twice, you should store the result in a temporary variable, and then check if that is defined.

Eg:

```
const foundElement = someArray.find(...)

if (foundElement) {
  console.log(foundElement.message)
}
```